# Show Related Product Price rule Products in the Cart Page

Tags: checkout, cart, related-products, rules

I am using this code in the Magento_Catalog (items.phtml.

```
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

    case 'related-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('YOU MAY ALSO LIKE');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'related':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
        if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('YOU MAY ALSO LIKE');
            $items = $block->getItems();
            $limit = 0;
            $shuffle = 0;
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'upsell-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'upsell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
            $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
            $shuffle = 0;

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'crosssell-rule':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('Add a gift bag');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = true;
        }
    break;

    case 'crosssell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('Add a gift bag');
            $items = $block->getItems();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = true;
        }
    break;
```

It is working fine.

I call my same template in the checkout_cart_index, but not getting any data.

The same data is coming correct on the PDP, but help me to achieve this in the cart page.

And also I want to get the get the collection of the products of the
specific product related rule